# Flutter, FutureBuilder snapshot error: type 'int' is not subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

When i am trying to get data from `Post`, i failed with this error.

[image]

It seems like nodeid variable is regarded as int type.
So I tried like this below

```
 factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      nodeid: nodeid.toString(),
```

But It is not working.

Here is the full code below.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  var params = {                              // Request를 위한 parameters 만듦.
    //TODO 서비스키 UTF-8 encoding이 필요함.
    "ServiceKey": utf8.encode('t8iGBTBFQc5nMq9ytuMZQ7jxR8ZMzohG%2F5o0i80f%2BehjFhMpkADfArAvFk%2BjHsPMFFEThQgejzujdpfou%2FDWng%3D%3D'),
    "cityCode": Uri.encodeFull("25"),
    "nodeId": Uri.encodeFull("DJB8001793ND"),
  };

  Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ArvlInfoInqireService/getSttnAcctoArvlPrearngeInfoList'); // URI 지정.
  final newURI = uri.replace(queryParameters: params); // queryParameters를 넣어 URI를 다시 만듦.

  final response = await http.get(
    newURI,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json", // The server is returning you XML, but you are trying to parse that as if it is JSON.
    },
  );

  /*
  final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  debugPrint('$responseJson'); //
  print('$responseJson'); //{response: {header: {resultCode: 99, resultMsg: SERVICE KEY IS NOT REGISTERED ERROR.}}}
  print(Uri.encodeFull("DJB8001793ND")); //I/flutter ( 7299): DJB8001793ND
  */
  //return Post.fromJson(responseJson);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
    return Post.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

class Post { 
  final String nodeid;
  //final String nodenm;
  //final int arrtime;
  //final int routeno;

  Post({
    this.nodeid, 
    //this.nodenm,
    //this.arrtime,
    //this.routeno
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      nodeid: json['nodeid'],
      //nodenm: json['nodenm'],
      //arrtime: json['arrtime'],
      //routeno: json['routeno'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp(post: fetchPost()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Post> post; 
  MyApp({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
            future: post,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) { // 만약에 Post에서 데이터가 존재한다면
                return Text(snapshot.data.nodeid); // 데이터 스냅샷을 보여준다.
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {        // << I got an error from here.  
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the XML file.

[image]

Is there anything i missed?

Comment: your service returns a different structure, why are you parsing as it was just one object?

Comment: @diegoveloper Do you mean i need to separate items? I don't get the meaning of different structures.

Comment: I wonder why you don't get error when try to parse the data

Answer (score 0):

If the servers returns you XML setting a flag will not change the data type.

Second I don't think the api is working properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <header>
      <resultCode>99</resultCode>
      <resultMsg>SERVICE KEY IS NOT REGISTERED ERROR.</resultMsg>
   </header>
</response>
```

I tried looking at the https://tago.go.kr/ to find the api myself for more info. But it's in Korean.

On to the original problem.

If the api is returning you any data that data is coming in XML format. Not a big deal though you can convert that to JSON then it is business as usual.

```
import 'package:xml2json/xml2json.dart'; // add this line
...
Xml2Json xml2json = new Xml2Json();  //Make an instance.

// Response is in xml, parse using xml2json
xml2json.parse(response.body);

var jsondata = xml2json.toGData(); 
// now we have data in json format 

// and are ok to continue
var data = json.decode(jsondata);
// data is json do what you need to
...
```

Comment: the server returns JSON also

Comment: I think  encoded ```serviceKey``` is a problem. Do you know how to do get utf8 encoded serviceKey by using ```Uri.encodeFull```?

Comment: Can you tell me which service you are using? I can probably look at the documentation myself?

Comment: @moficodes nvm! I did a stupid thing that i have been trying to encode a serviceKey which is already encoded :-0.. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
          if (snapshot.hasData) { // 만약에 Post에서 데이터가 존재한다면
            return Text(snapshot.data.nodeid); // 데이터 스냅샷을 보여준다.
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {        // << I got an error from here.  
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
```

Your type isn't getting changed to string. Change to:

```
          if (snapshot.hasData) { // 만약에 Post에서 데이터가 존재한다면
            return Text(snapshot.data.nodeid.toString()); // 데이터 스냅샷을 보여준다.
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {        // << I got an error from here.  
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
```

Comment: I think this error occurs since `snapshot.hasData` returns `False`.